# Python logger doesn't adhere to the set level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I created a logger in the Python3 interactive prompt:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.warn('bar')
bar
>>> logger.info('bar')
>>>
```

I'd expect `logger.info` to output the `bar` in this case, since I've explicitly set the logging level. But it's not the case here. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in your case neither should output anything since you haven't configured logging. You'll need to run `logging.basicConfig()` or add a handler to your logger to expect any output:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: logger = logging.getLogger('foo')

In [3]: logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

In [4]: logger.warn('foo')
No handlers could be found for logger "foo"

In [5]: logger.info('foo')

In [6]: logging.basicConfig()

In [7]: logger.info('foo')
INFO:foo:foo

In [8]: logger.warn('foo')
WARNING:foo:foo
```

As mentioned by larsks in the comments, in Python 3 logging is configured by default with level `WARNING` (which means you'll get output if you use `warning()` or any higher level by default). In your case, you either can call `logging.basicConfig()` to add a default handler to all loggers as in the example above, or add a handler to your logger:

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Comment: Your first sentence is only correct for Python 2.  In Python 3, you will get output on the console for log messages at `WARNING` and above even without calling `basicConfig`.

Comment: I believe `logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())` would also work. (Or you can add a custom handler to do whatever you want.)

Comment: Indeed, answer amended

Comment: I'm lost right now. If I were using Python2, I would add `logging.basicConfig` but in Python3...?

Comment: @marmistrz it's the same in both versions. Only difference is that in Python 3 there's a default handler with level `WARNING`.