# Info logger is not printing

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

Here is my code

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
logger.info('Hello World')
```

I expect it to print out 'Hello World'. It does not do so.

Could someone help me understanding why it does not print the message out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python logger doesn't adhere to the set level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068465/python-logger-doesnt-adhere-to-the-set-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a handler for your logger. The message is therefor propagated to the root handler which has a different log level.

The root logger can be configured as follows:

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Alternatively you can add a handler that forwards the messages to stderr:

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

This behavior is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).

Comment: Thanks Paul. Got it!